# iCarousel with auto layout

Tags: ios, ios7, icarousel, ios-autolayout

I´m using the iCarousel project in my universal app.

I create the main interface in a xib file.

[image]

The SBFGalleryView´s size will adjust depending if the app is running on iPad or iPhone. 
Due that, i add constrains to the iCarousel´s view so it adjust to SBFGalleryView´s size.

However the frame of the iCarouse´s never change. It keeps the always the frame size of the xib configuration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours I found the solution.

It has nothing to do with the iCarousel. The problem is that my iCarousel was added in a cell, and after using the iOS 8 SDK, it has a strange behavior when run on iOS 7, the `bounds` have a strange behavior, thats why iCarousel was never with the proper size.